# How to log in after upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS when there is no greeter (login screen)?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, lts

After upgrading my system (after it asked me to do so in the GUI) I am unable to log into it because there is no greeter/login screen but just a GUI screen with no prompt.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter this, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> to switch to console mode, login with username and password and then install a greeter with

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are greeted with terminal prompt you can type your login and password then `startx`. once you are logged in, open terminal and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.
hope it helped you.